# Batch: Parse a multiline string

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file, for-loop

I need a simple batch script which parses this string and get the filename from it:

```
OTR-Tool, v1.1.0
&FN=Filename.avi
&FH=EAA7508AAAD86AA4D8FAAE404BAFFA8729AA9C80AA4C8CBA
&OH=7FA2FAB108329105401003EAE224721BAFFA962E98F72750
&Sw=FALSE
&SZ=1198525032
&H=426060A8B8829808B8EAB802B0926082
```

I tried this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe %1') do if "%%A"=="&FN" set FN=%%B
```

But this doesn't work. I just get the entire output. Quick help somebody?

**upd** I tried also to execute just the following

```
otrtool.exe filename.key | find "&FN"
```

but I get the entire ouput again.

Comment: the file name is the first line?What's the final value of `FN`?

Comment: What's the final value of FN?

Comment: redirect the output to a file and check if it's in unicode.

Comment: I can't do it for some reason. `otrtool.exe > test.txt` should output the usage information of this program into the file. Though the file is created, its size is 0 bytes and the output of the executable goes to the console.

Comment: most probably it outputs to stderr.Try with `otrtool.exe > test.txt 2>&1`

Comment: and probably this is the issue with the whole script.

Comment: Yep. It was stderr. But the output is ANSI. Maybe stderr is the reason why the for-loop doesn't pick up the output?

Comment: ok.preapring the answer.

Comment: Yes! Adding `2>&1` to the script helps! Awesome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('%~dp0otrtool\otrtool.exe %1 2^>^&1') do if "%%A"=="&FN" set FN=%%B
```

try like that.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I should probably contact the developer or even try to fix the code by myself since I have the sources.

Comment: Or maybe just leave it as it is :) It works after all! Спасибо.